# multiple interfaces having same method that is finally implemented by class

Tags: java, interface

In an interview there are two interfaces B and C each having the same method public m1() class A implements B and C , If class A has to implement method m1, the implemented method would be of which interface.

at that time i was also confused that which method would be called can you please advise

```
public interface A {

public void show();
}

public interface B {

public void show();
}

public class Test implements A, B {

public static void main(String[] args) {

A a;
B b;
Test t = new Test();
a = t;
a.show();
b = t;
b.show();

}
```

Answer (score 4):

In Java, both interfaces overlap and there is just one method. It is not possible to provide two separate implementations (or to choose which one you want). If the two interface method definitions have incompatible return types, the class cannot extend both interfaces at the same time.

So, both `a.show()` and `b.show()` will call the exact same method.

In C#, you can disambiguate.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to implement `show` in the `Test` class.

You will only be able to implement it once in the `Test` class.

Keep in mind, the interfaces cannot, by definition, provide a default implementation of `show`.

Therefore, when you instantiate the `Test` class, the `show` method will only have one implementation at run-time. It will be the same implementation even if the objects have 2 different parent interfaces.

Comment: "the interfaces cannot, by definition, provide a default implementation" Is that still true in Java8?

Comment: You can try it if you are unsure, but it is true (otherwise they would be abstract classes or normal classes).